# Cypher query in Neoclipse cannot find nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neoclipse

I installed "neo4j-community-1.9-windows" and "neoclipse-1.9.1-win32.win32.x86_64" on one Win2008 R2 server. The Neo4j graph database files are located at "E:\neo4j_home" directory

`E:\neo4j_home\bin`

`E:\neo4j_home\config`

`E:\neo4j_home\data`

`......`

`E:\neo4j_home\system`

The graph database are running fine. I can see the nodes and the relationships at `http://localhose:7474/`, for example, I can see node 100 with `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/data/search/100/`

In Neoclipse, I set the conncetion URI to `E:\neo4j_home\data` or `E:/neo4j_home/data` and click "start/connect database" menu. The connection shows green. But when I do Cypher query in Neoclipse, it cannot find any nodes except node(0). For example:`start n=node(100) return n;` will get error: org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException:Node 100 not found

Did I set wrong conncetion URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the data URL should be `E:\neo4j_home\data\graph.db` instead of `E:\neo4j_home\data`.

Comment: Yes, `E:\neo4j_home\data\graph.db` is the right path. But I got `org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter` error when I tried to start the database. So I copied `graph.gb` to another folder, things are working now. Thanks.